# How to not accept custom parameter when another already exists

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-7

I've custom validation code in my controller

**Code**

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'query' => 'required_without:fruits|string|min:2|max:50',
    'page' => 'integer|max:10000000',
    "fruits" => "required_without:query|array|min:1|max:100",
    "fruits.*" => "required|string|min:2|max:50|distinct|exists:fruits,name"
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
}

$query = $request->get('query');
$fruits = $request->get('fruits');

// How to replace this block with Laravel core validation rules
if(($query && mb_strlen($query) > 1) && (is_array($fruits) && count($fruits))) {
    return response()->json([
        'errors' => [
            'You cannot use parameter "query" when parameter "fruits" already exists'
        ]
    ], 422);
}
```

When in request present `query` and `fruits` laravel doesn't return me error. When present field `query` I not need to filed `fruits` or when has `fruits` to `query`.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really the responsibility of validation.

You could make a custom rule for this ([documentation available here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#custom-validation-rules)), but I'd probably just check if fruits is present and then use that if it's there instead of query (I think you said fruits is higher priority right?)

Comment: Yes, I said that, but then I deleted the rule about the priority of the parameters. I accepted so that just using both parameters at the same time, then send an error message in response. So using the rules for validating the framework is impossible in your opinion, right? @jj

Comment: It's not impossible if you use a custom rule. It's just not one of the out of the box validation rules.